# Is there any way to experiment with the Bitcoin technology without having to buy actual bitcoins for use on the larger bitcoin network?

Tags: bitcoin-core, regtest, local

So, I'm just a curious person at this point, I've only just decided to look into Bitcoin and see how it works and what it does. But I'm not sure if I want to try out things on the larger bitcoin network, where there's real money of real value at stake. Is there a way I can setup a local bitcoin "network", with its own blockchain, etc. for testing purposes?

Comment: you can check these instructions to setup a local bitcoin network https://blog.starapps.io/setup-private-bitcoin-regtest-using-docker-a406127192df

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can run bitcoind in `regtest` mode. In that mode, you can produce your own "bitcoins" for testing purposes.